# Java Desktop Application Client-Server all in one

Tags: java, angularjs, javafx, client-server

I'm thinking about what might be the best solution to create a standalone client-server application in java with these features:
**Server**: it must provide APIs (probably rest?)
**Client**: javafx webview with angularjs to make requests to webserver.
**Loader**; it starts the server and the client;

The user can then manage the application directly from the webview or from the browser (to the server port)

This would also be able to create in the future a "cloud" version of the application, the client instead to query the localhost will perform to a remote server.

A solution of this type is correct?
What might be useful tools for its realization and how could it be structured?

I would like in particular a solution which does not require the use of a large Java Application Server, but something more simple that it can be included as a library.

Answer (score 1):

I thought same architecture which you think because it's easy. localhost binding, angularjs, bootstrap in java Webview. one of solutions is Spring MVC Rest API with embedded tomcat. it may be not lightweight.